# Dynamically replacing (or appending/prepending) to selection in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following paragraph in a plain text file that I am viewing (and editing) in Vim:

```
The synthesis and secretion of estrogens is stimulated by follicle-stimulating hormone (FSH), which is, in turn, controlled by the hypothalamic gonadotropin releasing hormone (GnRH). High levels of estrogens suppress the release of GnRH (bar) providing a negative-feedback control of hormone levels.
```

I am creating cloze deletion flashcards out of the text in this text file (ie. fill in the blank questions) which I will then feed to a home-made flashcard program I've written. My format for a cloze deletion is as follows:

```
The synthesis and secretion of [estrogens] is stimulated by [follicle-stimulating hormone]
```

This would produce two flashcards (when the text file is parsed by my flashcard program):

```
The synthesis and secretion of [...] is stimulated by follicle-stimulating hormone
The synthesis and secretion of [estrogens] is stimulated by [...]
```

I would like to automate the creation of these flashcards using Vim. The manual option would be to write a '[' to the beginning of each cloze deletion and a ']' at the end, but this is tedious and I'd like to use Vim's automation abilities. Ideally, I would like to be able to:

1. select a region of text to clozeify
2. execute a macro on this text

This macro would:

1. prepend '[' to the selection
2. append ']' to the selection

and exit.

How would I achieve this using Vim? When I try to use Ctrl-R in Visual Selection Mode it doesn't seem to work.

Essentially, the replacement I would like to do is:

`:%s/(CONTENT OF VISUAL SELECT)/[(CONTENT OF VISUAL SELECT)]/g`

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do with built-in commands:

```
v<motion>
c[<C-r>"]<Esc>
```

Breakdown:

- `v<motion>` is what you already do to visually select the text to transform.
- `c` cuts the visually selected text to the unnamed register and puts you in insert mode.
- `[` inserts an opening bracket.
- `<C-r>"` inserts the content of the unnamed register.
- `]` inserts a closing bracket.
- `<Esc>` puts you back into normal mode.

With that in mind, you can record a macro of the edit above and play it back on any visual selection:

```
v<motion>
qq
c[<C-r>"]<Esc>
q
```

then:

```
v<motion>@q
```

Breakdown:

- `qq` starts recording in register `q`.
- `q` stops recording.

or create a visual mode mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> c[<C-r>"]<Esc>
```

If that's something you need to do often, you should probably take a look at [Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) or [Sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich), which make all that considerably easier.

Reference:

```
:help c
:help i_ctrl-r
:help recording
```